# Edit "layers" property in mapbox layout by using dropdown menu (Plotly, Python)

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, dropdown, layer

I am trying to create a Mapbox graph using Plotly. All goes well in creating the traces and selecting which ones to display using the dropdown.

However, I am trying to draw layers over the map as well. When I do this without using a dropdown, it all goes fine. But when I try to add the layers as options using the "updatemenus" function, the layers will not be displayed.

The traces and base layout are created like this and work fine (a bit simplified, normally in a loop):

```
fig_dict = {
    "data": [],
    "layout": {}
}

data = dict(type='scattermapbox',
                lat=dft['lat'],
                lon=dft['lon'],
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(size=3,
                            color=dft['Color']),
                showlegend=False,
                 )
                                                                                                          
        fig_dict["data"].append(data)

layout = dict(legend=dict(orientation="h",yanchor="bottom",y=1.02,xanchor="right",x=1),
              mapbox= dict(accesstoken=mapboxtoken,
                           center=dict(lat=52.1436,lon=5.383),
                           style="dark", 
                           zoom=6.25)
            )


fig_dict["layout"] = layout
```

The layers are created like so (in the same loop as the traces):

```
        R = stand.iloc[0]['Distance in KM']/66.8
        R2 = (3/5)*R
        
        center_lon = dft.iloc[0,9]
        center_lat = dft.iloc[0,8]
        t = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
        circle_lon =center_lon + R*cos(t)
        circle_lat =center_lat +  R2*sin(t)
        
        
        coords=[]
        for lo, la in zip(list(circle_lon), list(circle_lat)):
            coords.append([lo, la]) 
        
        layer=dict(sourcetype = 'geojson',
                      source={ "type": "Feature",
                              "geometry": {"type": "LineString",
                                          "coordinates": coords
                                          }
                            },
                      templateitemname=dft.iloc[0,2],
                      visible=True,
                      color=  dft.iloc[0,13],
                      type = 'fill',   
                      opacity=0.5,
                      fill = dict(outlinecolor= 'white')
                    )
        layers.append(layer)
```

Finally the updatemenus part is structured like this (based on multiple traces created in the loop):

```
fig_dict["layout"]["updatemenus"] = [dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="Q3",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False],
                           {'title':'test1','mapbox':{'layers':layer1}}
                           ]),
                dict(label="Q4",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, True],
                            {'title':'test2','mapbox':{'layers':layer2}}
                           ])
                    ])
                    )]

fig = go.Figure(fig_dict)
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to structure "updatemenus", but to no succes. The above is my last try. Like I said, I have cut down my original code by a bit to keep it a little more tidy (I'm quite new to this), but the essentials are the same. If it's better to have the full code, I will provide it!

**Edit:**

The data looks as followed:

I have one dataset through which the script loops to create traces for all the individual locations on the map. Each ID (approx. 3k) has its own dot on the map. The collor corresponds to the location (dft):

```
    id  Location    lat lon
0   1   Leeuwarden  53.3238509  6.864812147
1   2   Leeuwarden  53.20375983 5.806213178
2   3   Enschede    52.28652282 6.845358477
3   4   Leeuwarden  53.18575506 5.833720622
4   5   Breda   51.81459037 5.851585979
5   6   Leeuwarden  53.20965451 5.777285517
6   7   Groningen   53.32373805 6.695864432
7   8   Leeuwarden  52.95470465 5.919419689
8   9   Leeuwarden  52.82104961 5.96997389
9   10  Enschede    52.50522699 6.612134113
10  11  Leeuwarden  53.15089124 5.844570929
```

Then for each location a layer is created on the map based on this dataset (stand):

```
    Location    lon lat Average distance in KM
0   Breda       4.234844574 51.45673726 15.1
1   Enschede    6.123570731 52.23459517 71.3
2   Groningen   6.234960418 53.12302082 22.2
3   Leeuwarden  5.795739613 53.19886105 30.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- from sample data and code, have generated figure.  No where in data do I find **quarter** as implied in **updatemenus**
- have used **geopandas** to help with calculating geometry for circles
- from this have created a **dict** which are the circle polygons by Location
- finally **updatemenus**   I did find you cannot just change the **layers**,  it needs to be complete **mapbox** setup.  i.e. **style**, **zoom**, **center** and **layers**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import requests, io
import plotly.express as px

dft = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    id  Location    lat lon
0   1   Leeuwarden  53.3238509  6.864812147
1   2   Leeuwarden  53.20375983 5.806213178
2   3   Enschede    52.28652282 6.845358477
3   4   Leeuwarden  53.18575506 5.833720622
4   5   Breda   51.81459037 5.851585979
5   6   Leeuwarden  53.20965451 5.777285517
6   7   Groningen   53.32373805 6.695864432
7   8   Leeuwarden  52.95470465 5.919419689
8   9   Leeuwarden  52.82104961 5.96997389
9   10  Enschede    52.50522699 6.612134113
10  11  Leeuwarden  53.15089124 5.844570929"""), sep="\s+")


stock = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """    Location    lon lat "Average distance in KM"
0   Breda       4.234844574 51.45673726 15.1
1   Enschede    6.123570731 52.23459517 71.3
2   Groningen   6.234960418 53.12302082 22.2
3   Leeuwarden  5.795739613 53.19886105 30.0"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)

# calculate geometry of areas with appropriate radius
stock = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    stock, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(stock["lon"], stock["lat"]), crs="epsg:4326"
)

utm = stock.estimate_utm_crs()
stock = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    stock,
    geometry=stock.to_crs(utm).apply(
        lambda r: r["geometry"].buffer(r["Average distance in KM"] * 1000), axis=1
    ),
    crs=utm,
).to_crs("epsg:4326")



# create scatter of points
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    dft, lat="lat", lon="lon", color="Location"
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom": 5},
    margin={"t": 25, "b": 0, "l": 0, "r": 0},
)


# build a dict of layers that corresponds to traces
layers = {
    t.name: {
        "source": stock.loc[stock["Location"].eq(t.name), "geometry"].__geo_interface__,
        "type": "line",
        "color": t.marker.color,
    }
    for t in fig.data
}

# # add circles as layers...
fig = fig.update_layout(mapbox_layers=list(layers.values()))

# # finally build menus...
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": q,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"visible": [t2.name == q or q == "All" for t2 in fig.data]},
                        {
                            "title": q,
                            "mapbox": {
                                "style": fig.layout.mapbox.style,
                                "center": fig.layout.mapbox.center,
                                "zoom": fig.layout.mapbox.zoom,
                                "layers": [layers[q]]
                                if q != "All"
                                else list(layers.values()),
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                }
                for q in stock["Location"].unique().tolist() + ["All"]
            ],
        }
    ]
)
fig
```

#### Location selected

[image]

#### all selected

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate reply! I am going to try and see if I can adjust my method to use geopandas and plotly express in the way you have done it.

Comment: if you update your question with some sample rows from **dft** I can use that as starting geometry.  It's not clear to me what / why **stand** dataframe is used. is it just a constant for size of radius?

Comment: I have added examples of my datasets, so I hope that makes things more clear. I think the main issue with my code is how I set up updatemenus. I see how you have done it, add layers to overall layout and then make them selectable through the menu. That is something I am going to try with my own code. I have adjusted the code you provided to my own data and that works as well with only the layers, so if I do not manage to adjust my own code, I will use yours and see if I can append it with all datapoints. Thanks again!

Comment: updated to use your sample data.  circles are now based on data in **stock**

Comment: I am very close to the solution. The dropdown now works (based on the quarter, not location). So the individual points and layers change how I want it. The only thing I am struggling with is that I want the layers to have the color corresponding to the different locations same as traces, but the dropdown menu to only be able to select the quarter. This means that the layers dict has to have only two selectable groups. However, if I add the color property there, all circles have the same color. I am looking for a way to add the color property to the feature part, but am having trouble with that

Comment: from a description can't really fully comprehend your challenge.  ask a new question with what you have (code and sample data) and I'll take a look

Comment: I figured it out! I structured the layers differently and added the individual colors to the loop. I then added all layers individually to fig.layout, and changed the way the layer group was selected in the dropdown via the updatemenus part. Thanks again for your help, couldn't have done it without you.